# What should I be testing from my service methods?

Tags: unit-testing

I have an odd dilemma. I have to use a separate dll for my database call actions. The classes are not written well and don't allow for inheritance or very good reusablity. They use A LOT of ref parameters instead of returning an object that is more useful. That being said I am trying to clean them up on my code side at least and hide away all of the not so useful information. I am stuck on what I should be testing in my service methods.

I am injecting a service into my apiController containing this method:

```
  public IEnumerable<ReportGroupName> Get(int key)
    {
        var webQueryGroupNames = new List<WebQueryGroupName>();
        //this method returns an object I have no use for
        //(the actual object returned not the ref object)
        _queryPermissions.GetWebQueryGroupNames(ref webQueryGroupNames, key);
        return Mapper.Map<List<WebQueryGroupName>, List<ReportGroupName>>(webQueryGroupNames);
    }
```

The question I can't decide an answer to is:

Should I add tests to check the value returned from the _queryPermissions.GetWebQueryGroupNames() method?

Should I just check the data returned from My Get method?

Should I just be verifying that the method was called since my service doesn't actually produce the data? (I have mapping tests around the automapper calls to verify they are properly mapping)

Comment: Why this comment: method returns an object I have no use for? it's clear that you do use it a line later

Comment: It refers to the actual return type of the method. Not the ref object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First layer of unit tests are a must.
Test that you Get Method returns the correct data, with various keys.

That goes without saying.

However, if you are not in control of this external assembly, you should run a few tests of your own to see that the internal workings of that "service" are not tampered with, remembering liskov substitution principle always.

This second layer of unit tests, is not "a must" always, but if you feel that changes can be made to that dll that you have no control over, or that changes are frequent, it's advisable to incorporate them.

Good luck!

Comment: It's an internal dll that is used by many processes we have in place. It could change but we wouldn't update our version unless something huge changed. So you suggest mocking the return value of the external dll(its a concrete class) and just verify my code is working?

Comment: Yes, use IoCs to inject mock methods of this dll.

Comment: You can always create Tests that check your Get methods and do NOT mock the internal dll method

Comment: If I didn't mock the data wouldn't I have to worry about false negative / false positive test results?

Comment: Again, and I'll try to be clearer, depending on the situation, sanity, release, nightly, whatever... you can chose what the degree of testing you want to use, just like log verbosity. I would suggest that you have one test that mocks and one test that does not mock, this I'm saying as something more generic, if this DLL was a service sometimes you wouldnt have access to it, so you would have to mock in order to move on with your coding, however when you DO have access to it, you would more that should use the test that does not MOCK.In your case you should probably use the one that doesnt mock